# Look up a string in a log to set an alert and generate thread dumps

Tags: notifications, thread

I need to write a script to create and alert and get thread dumps if a string (Related string is found) in a log file - `/tmp/area.log`. I am able to do this in 2 separate scripts so far but would like combine them into one.

Script 1: create an alert

```
filelocation=$1
string=$2
count=$(cat $1 | grep -i "$2" | wc -l)

if [[ "$count" -ge 1 ]];
 then
     echo "WARNING: There are $count occurrences of $2 in log file"
     exit 1
else
     echo "OK: No lines with $2 in log file"
     exit 0
fi
```

Script 2: Create thread dumps

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=$(ps -ef | grep java | awk '{print $2}')
N=3
INTERVAL=5

for ((i=1;i<=$N;i++))
do
  # d=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S)
  # dump="/tmp/Threaddump-$PID-$d.txt"
dump="/tmp/ThreadDump-`hostname`-`date '+%F-%H:%M:%S'`.gz"
echo $i of $N: $dump
  /opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/jstack -l $PID > $dump
   sleep $INTERVAL
done
```

Comment: @Inian, appreciate the corrections.

Comment: I am on mobile so a full critique will have to wait until tomorrow...but (1) use grep -q filename instead of convoluted shell logic, and (2) use pgrep with flags to get the exact pid you want instead of a fragile ps | grep | awk pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple, hope you are asking to do thread dump when you find the string in the log.

So when you script 1 finds string in the log you need to run the thread dump script. To do so you need to include the thread dump script in the  `if [[ "$count" -ge 1 ]];` true block.

```
filelocation=$1
string=$2
count=$(cat $1 | grep -i "$2" | wc -l)

if [[ "$count" -ge 1 ]];
 then
     echo "WARNING: There are $count occurrences of $2 in log file"
     PID=$(ps -ef | grep java | awk '{print $2}')
     N=3
     INTERVAL=5

     for ((i=1;i<=$N;i++))
     do
       # d=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S)
       # dump="/tmp/Threaddump-$PID-$d.txt"
     dump="/tmp/ThreadDump-`hostname`-`date '+%F-%H:%M:%S'`.gz"
     echo $i of $N: $dump
       /opt/jdk1.8.0_121/jdk1.7.0_40/bin/jstack -l $PID > $dump
        sleep $INTERVAL
     done

     exit 1
else
     echo "OK: No lines with $2 in log file"
     exit 0
fi
```

If you want the scrip to constantly look up the log and do the thread dump, you need to have a wrapper looping statement with 5-10 sec sleep and do this parsing and dumping logic continuously.

Code change for continuously monitoring the log.

Have a infinite loop after the file location statement, include a sleep for 60 seconds (It depends on how much sleep time you need) and end the loop in the last line. You need to do exception handling and you can demonize this script.

As mentioned by @wildcard you need to optimize for the parsing and PID part.

Comment: i would need to be constantly monitoring that log. How do i have a wrapper set.

Comment: included in my answer